# How does cumulative dynamic AUROC differ from traditional, binary-classification AUROC?

Tags: survival, roc

My goal is to predict components that are going to fail the soonest in order to replace them.

To date, we've deployed a binary classification model, with the positive class representing a component's failure within the next three months (a relatively arbitrary time period), and the negative class representing the component not failing within that time period. A given component could have multiple records, for each month it's active.

Lately, the team has thought this would be better represented as a survival analysis, basically modeling the time-to-event (the event being a component's failure). Methodologically, this makes sense.

The issue is I'm having difficulty measuring whether this survival model is actually better than the original, binary classifier, as far as our main performance metric AUROC goes.

Let's say the original model had an average AUROC (across the entire time span) of 0.65. In order to generate a more "apples-to-apples" comparison between the binary classifier and the survival model, I effectively converted the survival model's forecast–number of months until failure–to a "probability score" and then calculated AUROC with "failure within three months" as the dependent variable (same as the binary classifier). The performance is pretty similar–around 0.67. For my use case, not much to write home about.

*However*, when calculating the *cumulative dynamic AUROC* (see [here](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/sksurv.metrics.cumulative_dynamic_auc.html) and [here](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/evaluating-survival-models.html#Time-dependent-Area-under-the-ROC)), the performance of the survival model jumps up to around 0.75 for the 3-months-out time period.

This is somewhat of a surprise to me, and leads me to believe these metrics are fundamentally different, although when I read through the documentation linked above, I can't discern *how*.

In general, does anyone have any advice?

One thing that puzzles me in [the documentation linked above](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/evaluating-survival-models.html#Time-dependent-Area-under-the-ROC) is this comment:

> Cumulative cases are all individuals that experienced an event prior to or at time t (ti <= t), whereas dynamic controls are those with ti > t.

Does this mean the denominator for who's included in this dynamic AUROC calculation consists only of those who *experience the event* at any time in the study? That is, are right-censored individuals *excluded* from this calculation? I may be interpreting the comment too literally.